# RGB spectrum cycling multiple lamps

Tags: lighting

I am relatively new to blender and want to use it to animate something. My plan (explaining the relevant parts here) is to have a grid of lets say 10 by 10 lamps or bodys which light up. I want to create an effect where a rgb "wave" is cycling through the grid of lights. This video here shows exactly what I want to do:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jG1Kcjq6ZTk
Is there a way to automate this process a bit? Doing it 100% manual makes me face two challenges.

A: I would need to assign every lamp with a starting color to have a wave pattern in frame one and let them cycle from there on. This part is relatively simple. Not having this automatic would be okay for me.

B: More importantly I struggle with cycling through a rgb spectrum. When I set a keyframe for for example red and at the end for cyan it does not cycle through blue but through the middle of the color circle which is white. Is there a way apart from more keyframes to optimize this?

Comment: i would recommend using a node system. So you could use shader nodes, geometry nodes or animation nodes. maybe use that system, which you are most experienced on. for the rgb spectrum, wouldn't be a colorramp with hsl/far what you wanna have? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSkCW.png

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using the Vector Math: Modulo operation after a Mapping node and animating the X component of the location value.
The Modulo operation will basically say that once it reaches the entered value, start again from zero and keep on repeating.
[image]
Now if you are making that keyboard(and are not going to display the insides), then I would suggest that, put a plane with this material below the keys.

But, if you specifically want the lights for some reason, then add an empty to the scene and reference the location of this empty in the texture coordinate node.

(Also, for some reason, the setup for the lights will be like the image below. You have to use warp instead of modulo. They are similar, but I don't completely understand the difference. Also, you will have to set the min and max values in the Map Range node according to the horizontal dimensions of the object(/area in which the ligths are spread). One more thing, if you are going to move the lights, then make sure the empty moves with them.)
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try to make farmiliar with this.  This is deffinetely all new to me but I have some time to kill so I will work it out with your guide!
Idont want to specificly make a keyboard but have the same effect on something similiar. Basically cubes standing in a grid formation which are all individually light up.